# Why does this clock script fail on IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

http://home.comcast.net/~vonholdt/test/clock/index.htm

when the number on the right side, which shows the seconds, passes 7 all the other numbers flip to their following number until for 3 seconds (I mean until the right second number arrives to 0).
this only occurs in IE 8.

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#wrap').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);

    function middle(){

      wrapTop = ($(window).height() - $('#wrap').height())/2;
      wrapLeft = ($(window).width() - $('#wrap').width())/2;

      $('#wrap').animate({marginTop: wrapTop, marginLeft: wrapLeft}, 500);

    };

      middle();

      $(window).bind('resize', middle);

    function checktime(prevhour,prevmins,prevsecs){

      var now = new Date();

      var hour = now.getHours();
      if(hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;

      var mins = now.getMinutes();
      if(mins < 10) mins = "0" + mins;

    var secs = now.getSeconds();
    if(secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;  

      var hour = hour + "";
      var mins = mins + "";
    var secs = secs + "";

      if(prevhour != hour) {

        var prevhour = prevhour + ""
        var hoursplit = hour.split("");
        var prevhoursplit = prevhour.split("");

        if(prevhoursplit[0] != hoursplit[0]) numberflip('#hourl',hoursplit[0]);
        if(prevhoursplit[1] != hoursplit[1]) numberflip('#hourr',hoursplit[1]);

      };

      if(prevmins != mins) {

        var prevmins = prevmins + ""
        var minsplit = mins.split("");
        var prevminsplit = prevmins.split("");

        if(prevminsplit[0] != minsplit[0]) numberflip('#minl',minsplit[0]);
        if(prevminsplit[1] != minsplit[1]) numberflip('#minr',minsplit[1]);

      };

      if(prevsecs != secs) {

        var prevsecs = prevsecs + ""
        var secsplit = secs.split("");
        var prevsecsplit = prevsecs.split("");

        if(prevsecsplit[0] != secsplit[0]) numberflip('#secl',secsplit[0]);
        if(prevsecsplit[1] != secsplit[1]) numberflip('#secr',secsplit[1]);

      };



      function numberflip(which,number){

        if(number != 0) $(which).animate({marginTop: '-'+parseInt((number*140),10)+'px'}, 250, 'linear');

        if(number == 0) {

              var getmargin = parseInt(($(which).css('margin-top')), 10);

              $(which).animate({marginTop: parseInt((getmargin-140),10)+'px'}, 250, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).css("margin-top","0px")
          });

            };

      };

      setTimeout(function(){checktime(hour,mins,secs);}, 200);

    };

    checktime(00,00,00);

    $('#wrap').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

  });



</script>
```

HTML :

```
<div id="wrap">
        <img id="hourl" class="time" src="nums2.png" />
        <img id="hourr" class="time" src="nums10.png" />
        <img class="time" src="colon.png" />
        <img id="minl" class="time" src="nums6.png" />
        <img id="minr" class="time" src="nums10.png" />
        <img class="time" src="colon.png" />
        <img id="secl" class="time" src="nums6.png" />
        <img id="secr" class="time" src="nums10.png" />
        <div style="clear:left;"> </div>
        <div id="cover"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: One thing: you need to stop just randomly stuffing the `var` keyword before every assignment (and re-assignment) to local variables. It should be there, but only **once**, the first time a local variable is used in a function.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : tnx I'm newbie.    @Pointy : tnx for pointing it out it's a good practice but does not help my problem.

Comment: No worries. More re Pointy's point about `var`: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html

Comment: I tested more and it seems its only specific to IE8, it works well in IE7 & IE9.